# Conditions on $a,b,c,d$ such that $\gamma (t)$ is regular for all $t$?

Tags: differential-geometry

> I solved an exercise in my book and I was wondering if someone could
>   look at my answer and tell me if it is correct please?

The exercise is this: Let $\gamma (t) = (a \cos t + b \sin t, c \cos t + d \sin t)$. What are the conditions on $a,b,c,d$ so that $\gamma$ is regular? What is the equation of the curve when it is regular? What happens for other values of $a,b,c,d$?

My answer:

The derivative is given by $\gamma' (t) = (b \cos t - a \sin t , d \cos t - c \sin t)$ and the square of its norm is $(b \cos t - a \sin t)^2 + (d \cos t - c \sin t)^2$.

Therefore the norm is zero iff both terms are zero. The first term is zero iff

$$ b \cos t = a \sin t$$

But any scaled cosine curve has to cross any scaled sine curve at some point in time so to avoid that this equality never occurs either $b$ or $a$ has to be zero (while the other one has to be non-zero). Similarly for the second term.

As a consequence, the curve has to either be an ellipse or a line.

Comment: Having one of them zero is not enough to show the norm is zero. It needs to be zero for both terms. So, yes, if $ab\neq 0$ there is a solution to $b\cos  t-a\sin t=0$ but there is no reason to think the same $t$ has $d\cos t-c\sin t=0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe I am misreading you comment but I'm not trying to make the norm zero I am trying to avoid it being zero.

Comment: Right, but if $b\cos t-a\sin t=0$, the norm is not zero. So $b\cos t-a\sin t=0$ is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: Keeping track of contingencies "naively" looks vexing. Here are a couple of approaches, one consisting of a standard, general-purpose trig trick, the other an algebraic observation for this particular curve.

---

If $(a, b) = (0, 0)$ or $(c, d) = (0, 0)$, the curve is obviously not regular. Otherwise, there exist real numbers $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$, unique up to added integer multiples of $2\pi$, such that
$$
\frac{(a, -b)}{\sqrt{a^{2}+ b^{2}}} = (\cos\phi_{1}, \sin\phi_{1}),\qquad
\frac{(c, -d)}{\sqrt{c^{2}+ d^{2}}} = (\cos\phi_{2}, \sin\phi_{2}),
$$
and the sum formulas for the circular functions give
$$
\gamma(t) = \left(\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} \cos(t + \phi_{1}), \sqrt{c^{2} + d^{2}} \cos(t + \phi_{2})\right).
$$
Since the radicands are positive, $\gamma$ is regular if and only if
$$
\tilde{\gamma}(t) = \left(\cos t, \cos(t - \phi_{1} + \phi_{2})\right)
$$
is regular. It's now straightforward to determine when the velocity is zero.

---

Alternatively, for this particular curve you might notice that
$$
\gamma(t) = (\cos t)(a, c) + (\sin t)(b, d)
  = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
  \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \cos t \\
    \sin t
  \end{array}\right]
$$
is a "trigonometric linear combination" of a pair of vectors, a.k.a., the image of the unit circle (a regular curve) under the linear transformation with indicated matrix. Consequently, $\gamma$ is regular if and only if the matrix has rank $2$. (Why?)

This is probably the approach intended by the book's author, since it's easy to describe the image of $\gamma$ geometrically from knowledge of linear transformations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry for taking a few days before commenting. If we write $\tilde{\gamma}(t) = \left(\cos t, \cos(t - \phi_{1} + \phi_{2})\right)$ then it seems to me that it's not possible to choose $a,b,c,d$ such that $\gamma$ is regular for all $t$. Is this really true or am I missing something? I'm pretty sure that I am missing something since if we choose $a=d=0$ and $b,c\neq1$ then $\gamma $ is an ellipse and surely that's regular for all $t$?

Comment: The graph of $\cos(t - \phi_{1} + \phi_{2})$ is a horizontally translated cosine, so $\tilde{\gamma}$ fails to be regular if and only if the critical points of the component functions coincide, if and only if $\phi_{1} \equiv \phi_{2}$ (perfectly in phase) or $\phi_{1} \equiv \phi_{2} + \pi\pmod{2\pi}$ (perfectly out of phase). Each case corresponds to the vectors $(a, -b)$ and $(c, -d)$ being proportional, confirming the matrix conclusion. :)